# How to find first url user visited after logging in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I've written this reporting function which should show the `first URL the user has visited after logging in`.

I'm getting the url like so: `"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"`

I'm using this with the `wp_login hook` and just saving it to the db.

Perhaps there's a hook that fires right after `wp_login?`

Comment: I think you define contants as $counter =0; and increment $counter s/he logged in successfuly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_login` hook to get user logged in the first URL. Please put the code in your `functions.php` file.

```
function your_function( $user_login, $user ) {
        // your code
        if( ! session_id() ) {
            session_start();
        }
        $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['visited_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    }
    add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);
    if( ! session_id() ) {
            session_start();
    }
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
    if(isset($_SESSION['counter']) && $_SESSION['counter'] >=2){
        echo $_SESSION['visited_url'];
    }else{
        $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter']+1;
        $_SESSION['visited_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    }
```

How this code works:

step 1: Once user logged in we set `counter` and `visited_url` in the session.

step 2: check `counter` variable in session and greater equal to 2.

step 3: If it meets the condition we print first visited URL.

It is working code at my side.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.